# Is Dynamic Method Dispatch only meant to reduce compiling time

Tags: java, dispatch

I am new to JAVA and while studying I came across Dynamic Method Dispatch and this example confused me

```
class A {
   void callme() {
     System.out.println("Inside A's callme method");
  }
}

class B extends A {
  // override callme()
  void callme() {
    System.out.println("Inside B's callme method");
  }
}

class C extends A {
  // override callme()
  void callme() {
    System.out.println("Inside C's callme method");
  }
}

class Dispatch {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    A a = new A(); // object of type A
    B b = new B(); // object of type B
    C c = new C(); // object of type C
    A r; // obtain a reference of type A    

    r = a; // r refers to an A object
    r.callme(); // calls A's version of callme

    r = b; // r refers to a B object
    r.callme(); // calls B's version of callme

    r = c; // r refers to a C object
    r.callme(); // calls C's version of callme
  }
}
```

if I just do this

```
a.callme();
b.callme();
c.callme();
```

I get the same result. 
When i read about DMD by googling I didnt get satisfactory explanations. I just understood that it is late binding but not early binding and thats it. So it is just used to escape during compiling or is there something else. Is there any easy example to understand the benefit.

Comment: 'Dynamic dispatch' has *nothing* to do with reducing compile time. It is all about *run-time* behavior.

Comment: Perhaps focus on the statement "I get the same result" - why is *this* (getting the 'same results' for the *same object*, regardless of the *type of expression*) crucial to Subtype Polymorphism [in Java]? A very trivial case is `toString`: what should `((Object)x).ToString()` do?

Comment: It is also called "Late Binding" and this is how polymorphism is implemented in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I just read this https://www.sitepoint.com/subtype-polymophism/ and could somewhat understand what you are trying to say. I think I need to dive more into polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

This is more commonly referred to as dynamic binding. It provides polymorphic behavior (Polymorphism is an OOP concept).

In Java, dynamic binding is done based on the actual type of the object. This means that regardless of the **declared type** of the object, the invoked method body will be the one declared in the class that was used to construct it (the runtime class). This is the class with which `new` was used.

When you assign `r = a`, and call `r.callme()`, Java (at runtime) will see that the class of the object that the variable `r` points to is `A`, and will therefore run the implementation of `callme()` provided by the class `A`.
Likewise, when you reassign `r = b` and call `r.callme()`, Java will see that the class of the object is `B` and will run `B.callme`.

Regarding the "why" part, the [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) has states:

> The dictionary definition of polymorphism refers to a principle in biology in which an organism or species can have many different forms or stages. This principle can also be applied to object-oriented programming and languages like the Java language. ***Subclasses of a class can define their own unique behaviors and yet share some of the same functionality of the parent class.***